# Is this a good database design for course registration?

Tags: database-design

Specification:

1. One course registration application form can only have one application type.
2. One student can register (add or drop) to many courses. One course can be registered (add or
   drop) by many students.
3. Each application should be supported/completed by the head of program/academic advisor. If it
   is a co-curricular, then the coordinator will be responsible.
4. The application can only be processed if approved by the dean.
5. Each application should have a status for closer monitoring.

[image: ER diagram]

Here's the [design details on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HmCaBO-Ss1ROM1Dc5rvQEKTu2M8Mc7WC/view?usp=sharing).

My question is:

1. Is it a good idea to merge the coordinator, Head of program and academic advisor in one entity?
2. If so, how does it know if its a normal application or a co-curricular for application support purposes[Refer to specification no.3]? or it does not matter?
3. If it does not matter then if the course type is not related to the staff(eg. coordinator is not responsible for approving a "normal" course) then does it mean the value of coordinator_approval can be NULL?

Comment: No images, please.

Comment: sorry im still new to this site.

Comment: How do i represent relationships using text?

Comment: One possibility is dbfiddle.uk, where you could enter your design as create table statements.  Or PHPMyAdmin http://sforsuresh.in/generating-erd-using-phpmyadmin/.

Comment: How do i share the database i created?

Comment: You put the URL of the dbfiddle.uk in your question.

Comment: I used phpmyadmin, i exported it to pdf. i cant share it here

Comment: you'll need to put it on a file sharer.

Comment: Okay already shared it!

Comment: @GerardH.Pille ER diagram is a valid reason to attach an image; we discourage images of _code_ and _error messages_, but how do you really represent a diagram if not with an image? People shouldn't be required to use an off-site resource in order to understand the question.

Comment: "Ihow does it know if its a normal application or a co-curricular": What is "it"?  The database only "knows" what is registered.  Where did you intend to store this information?  Can the same course be normal for one, and co-curricular for another applicant?  In which case you could store it on application level, otherwise on course level.

Comment: @mustaccio, on this site, now and then reference is made to db- or sql-filddles, or the like.  Aren't they "off-site"?  I had difficulties reading (spending 45 years staring at computer screens weren't the cause, but certainly didn't help either) the image, sadly, the OP produced a PDF that was even harder to read, but on the other hand, the info was of a higher quality.  You can put anything on paper.

Comment: The "dean" entity has strange attributes for what I thought would be a person.

Comment: Yes the dean is a person but in this case I thought that the name wouldnt matter and only the approval of the dean matter. Because from reading on the specification, it looks like the dean is the one finalizing the application after it has been approved by either the head of program/coordinator. Is that correct?

Comment: I guess "it" refers to the Approval table where the Head of Program/Academic advisor will approve the normal course while the coordinator approves the co-curricular.      Because reading the specification, it says that HOP/AD->normal, Coor->Co-cu.                            
                                                                                                                                                    
The same course cannot be two types. For example, Badminton is a co-curricular while Database Design is a "Normal" course. So that means I have to store it in course right?

Comment: "the specification, it says that HOP/AD->normal, Coor->Co-cu"  The specs you gave don't say that.   I can't judge if you are right or wrong.   Your "dean" can only approve a single application.  Doublecheck if noone can take a normal course as co-curricular.

Comment: I think i my words may be confusing what I meant was that Each application should be supported/completed by the head of program/academic advisor. If it is a co-curricular, then the coordinator will be responsible. When you say the "Dean" can only approve a single application. Do you mean that the dean can only approve one application type (either "normal" or "cocu") or that the dean can approve an application one at a time?